# How do I correctly use a while loop in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

My program is supposed to infinitely ask the user to re-enter their username and password until it matches their first inputs, but the loop only runs once. Could this be because I am incorrectly using the break statements incorrectly or my nested for loops are implemented incorrectly?

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Entry denied");
Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your username:");
string username3 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your password");
string password3 = Console.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your username once more:");
    string username4 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your password once more");
    string password4 = Console.ReadLine();

    usernamematch = username == username4;
    passwordmatch = password == password4;
    if (usernamematch && passwordmatch) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You, at this point, would be redirected to   our webpage but this is c# programming.");
        break;               
    }
}
```

Comment: What is username ? How is that set ? Should it not check if username3 = username4?. Can you post the full code?

Comment: You're returning out of the while loop.  Take out the `return;` statements.

Comment: Thanks, Paul Carlton.

Comment: All your code paths end with a `return` or `break`, both of which exit the loop.

Comment: setting `passwordmatch = true;` on one line and then checking `if (passwordmatch == true)` on the next line seems a little unnecessary...

Comment: I take it you are a student.  Be aware that you have a potential **infinite loop** since there is no promise that the `while` condition will ever cease.  It's a better design to cap a limit on the number of attempts and use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: i have taken notice

Comment: i'll re-upload my newer work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This still has your infinite loop (NOT recommended), but it will do the job.  There's no need to use anything but "true" in while loop bool, because you're going to break out of it with the "break;".

```
Console.WriteLine("Entry denied");
Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your username:");
string username3 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your password");
string password3 = Console.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your username once more:");
    string username4 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your password once more");
    string password4 = Console.ReadLine();

    usernamematch = username == username4;
    passwordmatch = password == password4;
    if (usernamematch && passwordmatch) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You, at this point, would be redirected to   our webpage but this is c# programming.");
        break;               
    }
}
```